# Open Office Spreadsheet: sound alert when cell is positive

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I can colour a cell using conditional formatting.
But how can I set a sound alert when a cell has turned positive?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This requires a macro.  Put a listener on all cells that could affect the value of the cell you want to trigger the sound.  Have the macro save a copy of the value (the value, not the formula) of the target cell in a different cell.  When the listener is triggered, the macro checks the value of the target cell.  If the cell value is negative or zero, it updates the cell with the copied value.  If the cell value is positive, the macro compares to the copy.  If the value has changed to positive, then it makes a sound and copies the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic` and add the following code:

```vb
Sub ContentChanged (oCellChanged As Object)
    oSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(0)
    oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")
    If oCell.getValue() > 0 Then
        Beep
    End If
End Sub
```

Then go to sheet 1, right click on the tab and select `Sheet Events`.  Set the `Content changed` event to point to the macro.

Now it will beep when cell A1 is greater than zero.